# Ehcache - Replicated Caching using RMI

Tags: java, rmi, ehcache, distributed-caching

I tried using the ehcache and it worked. And I am just trying to implement distributed caching with ehcache RMI. I followed the steps provided in the url: http://ehcache.org/documentation/distributed_caching_with_rmi.html?cf03800515=21D4D871!NTAxODEzNDE0OmNvcnByYWRpdXNzc286vsRypkVtSPb7t3MnL22gFQ==#

But I could not find the distributed caching working...

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//<remotemachineip>:<i want to know what port id should be given here>/deviceCache1"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
properties="hostName=<localmachineip>,port=<i want to know what port id should be given here>,
socketTimeoutMillis=120000"/>
```

I gave some port number and I am having the standalone java code in two machines. 
First, I run the main program in my friend's machine which puts data to "deviceCache1" and I try to access that cache in my main program. But I don't find any connection happening between two machines.

I may sound silly, but I need to know few things regarding caching. Please some one clarify my doubts and help me.
So, My questions are:
1. What port ids need to be given in ehcache.xml in both machines?
2. Do i need to have some windows service enabled to use rmi ports?
3. Do i need to add any other code for connection between 2 machines?

Please help me asap.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Due to comments size limitation & this will answer your question

Config on server 1 will be like this

```
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001,socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>
```

Config on server2 will be like this

```
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
    properties="hostName=localhost, port=40002,socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>
```

If you are still facing the issue, paste your ehcache.xml. Kindly accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Server1 - <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//server2:40002/CacheName1"/>
On server2
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//server1:40001/CacheName1"/>

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to add cacheEventListenerFactory to the cache(which needs to be replicated)

memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
      diskPersistent="true"
      timeToLiveSeconds="86400" 
      maxElementsOnDisk="1000">

You can give any port(which is not being used by system

Comment: I have a <cacheEventListenerFactory> associated with my <cache> entry. But whatever port I give in provider and listener, am not seeing any communication happening between two systems. I am trying to access the cache from second machine, and from second machine am trying to access cache from my machine. But no response from both... so i wonder, if i need to give any specific port/do we need to enable any RMI related services / do we need to write any code to establish the connection or registering the port.